# PHP coding style; spacing with parentheses

Tags: php, coding-style, parentheses

Which coding style choice is considered preferable by most developers?:

```
if ( ! isset($var) ) {
```

OR

```
if (!isset($var)) {
```

OR

```
if ( !isset($var) ) {
```

OR

```
something else...
```

Comment: I suggest to avoid bad coding style, examples that you provided are good, you can use any of them, please read this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-youre-a-bad-php-programmer/

Comment: see psr-1 (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the third option:

```
if ( !isset($var) ) {
```

Here's why:

- It's easy to read
- It separates the condition from the  `if`  brackets making it less confusing
- I don't know... personal preference?

It boils down to this: use whatever style you're comfortable with. There's no *best*.

Comment: i lean towards that too, but I do worry that the `!` could get missed

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this question is really subjective, Is hard to tell which one is the most preferred one, for me the three are ok, It depends and how do you want to do it, and keep the same format all over the file.

If you are wondered about the cleanest way to coding, you can check this:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($a != 2) {
    $a = 2;
}
```

At least, that's how Zend looks at it:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question because the nuance is with the isset() which adds parenths